# Array of Check Boxes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of check-boxes for a form field.

```
<% PROPOSAL_EXPERIENCE_TYPE.each do |p| %>
    <%= f.check_box( :proposal_experience_type, { :multiple => true }, p, nil) %>
    <%= p %> <br />
<% end %>
```

where this PROPOSAL_EXPERIENCE_TYPE is a constant

```
PROPOSAL_EXPERIENCE_TYPE = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

and the proposal_experience attributes are passed like this

```
.......,"proposal_experience_type"=>["B", "D"],........
```

and inside my MySQL database the values for proposal_experience are saved like

```
---
- B<br>
- D<br>
```

I'm trying to save these values with a coma separated one.. like

```
B, D
```

How to do this..?

Comment: You want to save it in a single row?

Comment: @RSB yes something like B, D

Comment: Does your model have `serialize proposal_experience_type` ?

Comment: try changing it to `serialize :proposal_experience_type, Array` and this should save your proposal types as an array.

Comment: thats not what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting it as array, change it to string by using `join`, before saving do this

```
params["proposal_experience_type"] = params["proposal_experience_type"].join(',') #=> "B,D"
```

Comment: oke.. this one saves it like 
'--- Contracts,Grants,Tenders
...<br>'
i want it to get saved just like Contracts, Grants, Tenders

Comment: Where is <br> coming from

Comment: Sory it was that serialize that i forgot to delete.. Now its working fine..
But thing is this is a form and i want my checkboxes to be preselected with these values when i take it for editing.. if this is coma separated then how should i do that

Comment: Just split it when you are fetching it, use `.split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

```
sanitize.(params["proposal_experience_type"]).split(',')
```